# After uploading my HTML/CSS/JS files to cPanel, I can view my website with the HTML/CSS working, but the JavaScript from my .js file is not working

Tags: javascript, cpanel

Hello all: I am very new to web developing and I just got my HTML/CSS basic website to show up after getting files uploaded and organized in cPanel. However, when I added my .js file, it looks to me like it is not working. The .js and HTML files are in the same directory and I am linking it with the script tags properly but when I test it (console.log("hello world")), nothing is happening. Can anyone help me out here or point me in a direction to figuring this out?

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Barlow+Condensed|Karla|Vollkorn&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9394b48c69.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
  <title>Timothy Peng</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Check for the console for errors output. Also try accesing directly to the file. If you can share your site I can check it

Comment: @Frankusky turns out that my HTML file wasn't the latest version when I uploaded to cPanel! I was looking at my GitHub repo, and thought I was running the website from there. Thanks for your willingness to help though; cheers!!